# finding repeated characters using re.match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out why the following code prints "2" instead of "1"

```
import re

line = "9111222"
m = re.match( r'.*(\w)\1+', line)
print m.group(1)
```

I understand that re.match attempts to match at the beginning of the string, but I assumed it would then see the "111" and print "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` means greedy, add a `?` behind to make it non greedy if you were interested on the 111

```
import re

line = "9111222"
#                 ^
m = re.match( r'.*?(\w)\1+', line)
print(m.group(1))
# '1'
```

Answer (score 4):

The `*` quantifier in regular expressions is *greedy*, meaning that it will try to match as many as possible. In your string, `91112(2)2` will allow `.*` to match the most characters, so that's the match the engine selects, with the second-to-last `2` being captured.

See https://regex101.com/r/IkM5gX/2